# Using the results of LLVM alias analysis from an LLVM loop pass

Tags: llvm, static-analysis

I have an **LLVM loop pass**, and I need to check whether
**two values may alias to one another**. If I first run an alias analysis pass, and then the loop pass, **how can I query the results of the AA pass?**
It should probably be something similar to:

```
virtual bool runOnLoop(Loop *loop, LPPassManager &LPM)
{
    Value *v1 = getValueSomehow();
    Value *v2 = getValueSomeOtherWay();

    // EDITED with compor's answer
    AliasAnalysis *AA = &getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults();

    if (AA->isNoAlias(v1,v2))
    {
        errs() << "OK";
    }
}
```

However when I run it with this opt command (I put the aa pass first)

```
opt            \
-basicaa       \
-loop-simplify \
-instnamer     \
-indvars       \
-simplifycfg   \
-view-cfg      \
-o input.ready.bc input.bc
```

I get this runtime error:

```
opt: PassAnalysisSupport.h:236: [...]:
Assertion `ResultPass && "getAnalysis*() called on an analysis that was not " "'required' by pass!"' failed.
...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

EDIT:

It does **not** suffice to simply put the -basicaa pass first to opt.
Indeed, like compor said, one has to override the getAnalysisUsage,
and explicitly say which passes are required.

```
struct StaticAnalyzer : public LoopPass
{
    static char ID;
    StaticAnalyzer():LoopPass(ID){}

    void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override
    {
        AU.addRequired<AAResultsWrapperPass>();
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt do as LLVM does; for example, in this case have a look in `llvm/lib/Transforms/Scalar/DeadStoreElimination.cpp`.

Using the `llvm::legacy::PassManager` this is done by adding the Alias Analysis as a requirement of your pass:

```
void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
    AU.addRequired<AAResultsWrapperPass>();
    [...]
}
```

and then accessing the analysis results in the `run()` method:

```
AliasAnalysis *AA = &getAnalysis<AAResultsWrapperPass>().getAAResults();
```

Also, note that you can "plug" and combine various alias analyses (plural) via the commandline (mentioned [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html)), e.g.

```
opt -basicaa [...]
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it but it crashes ... I added the assertion fail in the question.

Comment: I was about to suggest promoting your pass to function or module pass and use the `LoopInfo` analysis as well, just in case it's something in the setup that is in the way. Good that you made it work.